# Error Parsing '&' Character Using Woodstox Parser

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, woodstox

Java: 1.6
Woodstox: 4.1.4

I'm currently trying to make Woodstox xml parser my friend. But beginning is really hard :)
I have a small? problem when parsing xml like this one:

```
<teams>
    <team id="team1">Mom & Dad</team>
    <team id="team2">Son & Daughter</team>
</teams>
```

It is simple, but unfortunately I'm getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" [com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxLazyException] com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character ' ' (code 32) (missing name?)
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [2,24]
```

This happens because of character &.

Is it possible to read xml successfully without getting this exception?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`&` is an invalid character and should appear escaped as `&amp;` or enclosed in a CDATA section.

```
<teams>
    <team id="team1">Mom &amp; Dad</team>
    <team id="team2"><![CDATA[Son & Daughter]]></team>
</teams>
```

From:  http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax

> The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) MUST NOT
>   appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters,
>   or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. If
>   they are needed elsewhere, they MUST be escaped using either numeric
>   character references or the strings " `&amp;` " and " `&lt;` "
>   respectively.

Comment: Don't forget the other XML character entities: `&lt;` `&gt;` `&apos;` `&quot;`.

Comment: CDATA came to my rescue. Thanks for this solution